# write a program that reads a sentance and write it on a file separating each word on a different line of the file (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, file, stringtokenizer

I need to do this exercise with java and I don't even know where to begin, someone told me I should use StringTokenizer and I have no idea how to use it or do anything else on the exercise. Can some of you help me? I'm watching tutorials on java but I don't get nothing ...

Comment: If you want help, please read [ask] and [the on-topic section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) so that you write a question that will get answered.

Comment: Are we doing your homework for you?  Yes, a StringTokenizer would work just fine here to break up your original sentence.  Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), it gives you a good example.

Comment: The string tokenizer class allows an application to break a string into tokens.Its very simple just use StringTokenizer class to split the input string and write it to a file using OutputStream. You can [refer for StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) [refer for OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to take your string and change it into a list of words. This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
String initialString = "..."; //Whatever your string is
String[] words = initialString.split(" "); //Split by spaces to get word list
```

Next, you have to open a file that you can write the words to. You create an instance of `PrintWriter`, whose constructor two parameters (the file name and the encoding, usually `UTF-8`). You create the PrintWriter with the following code:

```
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
```

Just remember that whatever file name you specify to PrintWriter will be completely overwritten!

Finally, you loop through the list of words and write each one to the file with a modified for-loop:

```
for (String word : words)
    write.writeln(word);
```

and close the writer:

```
write.close();
```

Thus, the final code looks like this:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class WriteWords {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //You can obviously change this :)
        String sentence = "I am using Java to do text processing instead of Perl.";
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        //Change "output.txt" to whatever your file is
        PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
        for (String word : words)
            write.writeln(word);
        write.close();
    }
}
```